# facebook does not logout properly in ios app.cannot switch users

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

i am using the facebook login button provided by the fb sdk for implementing the facebook login in my app.When i am logging out the facebook button does change back to login again.but when i click on it,the safari app opens showing "you have alreay authorised the app"click confirm or cancel.Actually i needed the facebook login and password screen here.I cannot switch user until i reset the simulator.how to reset the contents in safari programmatically each time i logout so that the login screen is shown each time.

Please note that when i clear the website data of safari manually it shows the login page again.can it be done programmatically.

code i am using for login is as follows

```
//creating the login button
 FBLoginView *loginView =
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
     @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];
    loginView.frame=CGRectMake(50, 500, 225, 55);
    loginView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:loginView];

//delegate method when logged in
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {


    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[user objectForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"LoggedInUserID"] ;


    [self checkandsaveNewUserInBackend:user];




  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Login" sender:self];

}




//logout code
- (IBAction)logoutButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];


    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: yes ,but the same result as before...the fb web ui is keeping the loggedin users session alive...and so cannot switch profile

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        [FBSession.activeSession close];
        [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

May work for you...

And for clear cookies from browser...follow this link  \

http://www.iossnippet.com/snippets/web/how-to-delete-cookies-nshttpcookie-in-objective-c-ios/

Comment: from the app the login details are going but still safari is keeping some cookie or the session is still active in safari,so it is still showing "you have already authorized the app".it is not going to the login screen

Comment: ya programatically...did you know  `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`

Comment: Both of answer for you is correct...follow as per your requirement

Comment: actually the requirement is to clear the cookies in safari not within the app.the code you gave is for the cookie in the app

Answer (score 1):

try this it user clicks on logout and remove all keys stored in userdefault/cookies

```
  NSLog(@"Logged out facebook");
 NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
 NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
   NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
   NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
   if(domainRange.length > 0)
   {
       [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
   }
}
```

Comment: the requirment is that the cookie should be cleared from safari not from the  app

Answer (score 1):

In the

```
//logout code
- (IBAction)logoutButtonPressed:(id)sender {
```

Use following code

```
 if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
        || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {



    // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
    // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

    // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
} else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
             }];
}
```