# How to logout using FBSDKLoginKit after login?

Tags: ios, swift2, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

This is what I do in my controller:

```
let button = FBSDKLoginButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 50))
button.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_friends"]
view.addSubview(button)
```

After `viewDidLoad` I click that button, write my login and password and since then I always have such view:

[image]

How to log out from that? It appears always, even I remove the app from Simulator. What is wrong?

Comment: Did you remove the Wishlist app from your Facebook App Settings? (Settings > Apps)?

Comment: do you mean settings in iOS?

Comment: No, I mean in Facebook.

Comment: @TomasCamin Ok, I understand, but is it possible to do this in code? For example on action button.

Comment: reset your simulator

Answer (score 0):

1> GOTO the safari app and open facebook.com

2> Open your account preference.

3> log out form your account.

## OR

1> GOTO "Setting".

2> Click "Safari".

3> Click "Clear History and Website Data".

Also you remove app Permission from facebook than go to Profile-->APP-->find your application name -->remove data.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226950/facebook-ios-sdk-logout-question

Comment: It is not the question about `Facebook-ios-sdk` because it is DEPRECATED. The question is about `FBSDKLoginKit` so simply it is not helpful.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk it is not possible to clear the cookies from our app to safari programmatically. see the discussion .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207893/facebook-does-not-logout-properly-in-ios-app-cannot-switch-users

Comment: I suppose you do not understand sth. `FBSDKLoginButton`'s delegate has a method: `loginButtonDidLogOut()`. Since there is such method, there must be a way to call this. How to do this? IN other words how to logout in code?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk , FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager logOut]; or [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];

Comment: It doesn't make me able to login again with `login` and `password`. I begin to doubt:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89585/discussion-between-ilesh-and-bartlomiej-semanczyk).

Answer (score 0):

Below two methods **must be** implemented in `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

And then once you click `Log In with Facebook` and then `OK`, your `FBSDKLoginButton` will change to:

[image]

Once you tap this, you are able to logout with following dialog:

[image]